# Return a fat/thick pointer as an out parameter

Tags: ada

I am having trouble creating a thick pointer. My current set of declarations look like this:

```
type Index_Typ is mod 20; -- will be larger in real life
type Data_Buffer_Typ is array (Index_Typ range <>) of Integer; --unconstrained array type
type Data_Buffer_Ptr is access all Data_Buffer_Typ; -- a thick pointer, contains the bounds of array subtype pointed to and address..

Data_Buffer : aliased Data_Buffer_Typ (Index_Typ) := (others => 0); -- this is private
type Result_Typ is (Ok, Overflow, Null_Pointer);

   procedure Retrieve (Index    : in     Index_Typ;
                       Len      : in     Index_Typ;
                       Data_Ptr :    out Data_Buffer_Ptr;
                       Result   :    out Result_Typ) is
   begin
     -- assuming range checks are ok, what goes here ?
   end Retrieve;
```

so if i declare:

```
Ptr : Data_Buffer_Ptr := null;
```

and given a call of `Retreive (2,3, Ptr,Result);` how do i end up with a pointer that points at elements 2,3 & 4 of `Data_Buffer` ?

Notes:

- Yes i know passing out an array slice will probably be done as a
  pointer anyway, but we want to explicitly use pointers, not
  implicitly (and not my choice!).
- Yes i have experimented, i usually get : (`object subtype must statically match designated subtype`) error message..
- Where possible use of `new` to be avoided.

Comment: (a) if you must use suffixes to indicate that a name designates a type, why not use `_Type`? or just `_T`? (b) you don't show us `Result_Typ` (c) are both `Data_Ptr` and `Result` really `out` parameters?

Comment: @SimonWright (a) company coding standards. (b) Result_typ is an enum. Not really relevant, just designates if the operation is successful or why not (overrun end of buffer type errors). (c) Yes & Yes.

Comment: @SimonWright - in (c) are you suggesting an `in out` may be more appropriate ?

Comment: @SimonWright - I'm guessing their standards were written by a big fan of [Ken Thompson](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10893/what-did-ken-thompson-mean-when-he-said-id-spell-create-with-an-e). ;-)

Comment: re: (c) - no, I thought that Data_Ptr might be the input, Result the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, though I have to say it's repulsive! Note the order of the components in `Fat_Pointer`, which is the opposite to what I started with, and the size of the record on this 64-bit machine (I put the rep clause in to have make the order explicit, it works fine without). Also, I think you're stuck with the `new`.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
with System;
procedure Fat is
   type Index_Typ is mod 20;
   type Data_Buffer_Typ is array (Index_Typ range <>) of Integer;
   type Data_Buffer_Ptr is access all Data_Buffer_Typ;
   Data_Buffer : aliased Data_Buffer_Typ (Index_Typ) := (others => 0);
   type Result_Typ is (Ok, Overflow, Null_Pointer);

   procedure Retrieve (Index    : in     Index_Typ;
                       Len      : in     Index_Typ;
                       Data_Ptr :    out Data_Buffer_Ptr;
                       Result   :    out Result_Typ)
   is
      type Bound is (Lower, Upper);
      type Bounds is array (Bound) of Index_Typ;
      type Bounds_P is access Bounds;
      type Fat_Pointer is record
         The_Data : System.Address;
         The_Bounds : Bounds_P;
      end record;
      for Fat_Pointer use record
         The_Data at 0 range 0 .. 63;
         The_Bounds at 8 range 0 .. 63;
      end record;
      function To_Data_Buffer_Ptr
      is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (Fat_Pointer, Data_Buffer_Ptr);
      Answer : constant Fat_Pointer
        := (The_Bounds => new Bounds'(Lower => Index,
                                      Upper => Index + Len - 1),
            The_Data => Data_Buffer (Index)'Address);
   begin
      Result := Ok;
      Data_Ptr := To_Data_Buffer_Ptr (Answer);
   end Retrieve;

   Ptr : Data_Buffer_Ptr := null;
   Result : Result_Typ;

begin
   for J in Data_Buffer'Range loop
      Data_Buffer (J) := Integer (J);
   end loop;

   Retrieve (2, 3, Ptr, Result);

   for J in Ptr'Range loop
      Put_Line (J'Img & " => " & Ptr (J)'Img);
   end loop;
end Fat;
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, Ill take this as proof that we shouldnt try it !